# Regex parsing of a multi-line entry with optional newline characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am almost a novice in regex. I am trying to parse the outputs from a CommandLineInterface (CLI). The output typically is the contents of files and folders under a specified path. The following could be the potential different formats of the output.

## CLI Output format 1

```
d:\ARCTest\_MyProject\Sources\CMCore\project.pj subsandbox <CRLF>
<space> d:\ARCTest\_MyProject\Sources\CMInterfaces\project.pj subsandbox <CRLF>
<space> d:\ARCTest\_MyProject\Sources\CMImplementation\project.pj subsandbox <CRLF>
<space> d:\ARCTest\_MyProject\Sources\Übersicht und fragen\project.pj subsandbox <CRLF>
<space> d:\ARCTest\_MyProject\Sources\CMAccess.sln archived 1.15 <CRLF>
<space> d:\ARCTest\_MyProject\Sources\übersicht und fragen.xlsx archived 1.1
```

For format 1, before the second line onward there is a CRLF and an addition space (I have denoted this using the symbols `<space>` and `<CRLF>`, please note that this is not part of the actual output). The CRLF might not be always present in the output, in other words it is optional. The first four are paths to mks folders and the last two are files in mks. What I want is all matches that points to folders (those end in \project.pj, including the project.pj) and matches that point to files (those end with the word archived, excluding the text archived).

## CLI Output format 2

```
CMCore/project.pj subproject <CRLF>
CMInterfaces/project.pj subproject <CRLF>
CMImplementation/project.pj subproject <CRLF>
Übersicht und fragen/project.pj subproject <CRLF>
CMAccess.sln archived <CRLF>
übersicht und frögen.xlsx archived
```

For format 2, before the second line onward there is a CRLF (I have denoted this using the symbol , please note that this is not part of the actual output). The first four are paths to mks folders and the last two are files in mks. What I want is all matches that points to folders (those end in \project.pj, including the project.pj) and matches that point to files (those end with the word archived, excluding the text archived).

I was almost successfull to parse the folders in both cases using the rgular expression `^([^\r\n]\w+.+?\.pj)`, but it failed to fetch the first line from output format 1. I was not able to figure out a solution to parse the files in both the formats. Any solution would be of great help.

Please let me know if I need to provide more information on this.

Thanks in advance,
Joe.

Comment: You have lots of potential problems using unquoted path names that include spaces. For example, you'll have a real tough time with the path `d:\ARCTest\_MyProject\Sources\this.pj is a mess\project.pj`. Can you modify your output to quote the path names?

Comment: @JimMischel That kind of a path won't ever come up, as I said these entries are read from the CLI. These are paths to files and folders stored in MKS Server. The .pj extension is the default extension that MKS uses to name a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
([\w ]\S+\/*)*\w([\w]+\.(\w+))

using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string patternDir = @"([\w ]\S+\/*)*\w([\w]+\.(pj))";

        string pathDir = @"d:\ARCTest\_MyProject\Sources\CMInterfaces\project.pj subsandbox ";
        string pathFile = @"CMAccess.sln archived";

        Console.WriteLine((Regex.IsMatch(pathDir,patternDir))? "It's dir!" : "It's not a dir");
        Console.WriteLine((Regex.IsMatch(pathFile,patternDir))? "It's dir!" : "It's not a dir");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I added a couple of edits to your solution, so that I could fetch the folders and files separately. I also got rid of the äÄ condition as my application need to support other languages as well. I will post them as two separate comments to bypass the comment length validation.

Comment: I updated your solution like the one below to fetch files.    (?<=[\s ])(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[ \w\.]+\\[ \w.$]+)\\(?:[ \w]+\\)*\w([ \w.])+(.archived)(?=[\s\S])|(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\.]+\\[\w.$]+)\\(?:[\w]+\\)*\w([\w.]+(.archived))|(?:[\w]\S+\/)*\w([ \w.]+(.archived))

Comment: For folders I updated the regex like this    (?<=[\s ])(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[ \w\.]+\\[ \w.$]+)\\(?:[ \w]+\\)*\w([ \w.])+(.pj)(?=[\s\S])|(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\.]+\\[\w.$]+)\\(?:[\w]+\\)*\w([\w.]+(.pj))|(?:[\w]\S+\/)*\w([ \w.]+(.pj)). Could you please review these for any pitfalls. Thanks.

Comment: Please note that the <CRLF> and <space> are not present in the original input string. I just added them in my post so that everyone could notice them easily. The reason for me to omit the file extensions like -sln, .xlsx etc is because the path could contain any files.

Comment: if you gonna use not only the extensions you've specified but any other check for simple regex above or here http://regexr.com?37jpg

Comment: The only two things that I could use as an identifier to distinguish between a folder and a file is that folders will always have '.pj' file extension in the entry and files will have the 'archived' keyword against them. I won't be able to specify a set of file extension as in your proposed solution. Also, as mentioned earlier since my app need to support almost all languages we won't be able to mention any specific char set (äÄöÖüÜ etc) as well. That's why I tried to get rid of any mention to these in your solution. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I will mark your suggestion as accepted answer, as soon as I run my unit tests. Thanks, its working with all the combinations that I tried. Fingers crossed :)

Comment: Is there anyway we could optimize this to fetch only entries with .pj and entries that does not contain .pj.

Comment: i modified my answer, now you should read your CLI output line by line and pass it through some kind of check